Cuda error when trying to setup a project using pytorch
I was trying to follow the instructions of an opensource repo for segmentation. At some point I ran python setup.py install and got this error.
!!
  self.initialize_options()
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing pointops.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to pointops.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to pointops.egg-info/requires.txt
writing top-level names to pointops.egg-info/top_level.txt
reading manifest file 'pointops.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'pointops.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
running build_ext
/home/makogan/anaconda3/envs/sam3d/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py:425: UserWarning: There are no g++ version bounds defined for CUDA version 11.8
  warnings.warn(f'There are no {compiler_name} version bounds defined for CUDA version {cuda_str_version}')
building 'pointops._C' extension
/home/makogan/anaconda3/envs/sam3d/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py:628: UserWarning: Can't initialize NVML
  warnings.warn("Can't initialize NVML")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 16, in <module>
    setup(
  File "/home/makogan/anaconda3/envs/sam3d/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 103, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/home/makogan/anaconda3/envs/sam3d/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 185, in setup
    return run_commands(dist)
  File "/home/makogan/anaconda3/envs/sam3d/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 201, in run_commands
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/home/makogan/anaconda3/envs/sam3d/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/home/makogan/anaconda3/envs/sam3d/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 989, in run_command
    super().run_command(command)
  File "/home/makogan/anaconda3/envs/sam3d/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/home/makogan/anaconda3/envs/sam3d/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 84, in run
    self.do_egg_install()
  File "/home/makogan/anaconda3/envs/sam3d/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 132, in do_egg_install
    self.run_command('bdist_egg')
  File "/home/makogan/anaconda3/envs/sam3d/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/home/makogan/anaconda3/envs/sam3d/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 989, in run_command
    super().run_command(command)
  File "/home/makogan/anaconda3/envs/sam3d/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/home/makogan/anaconda3/envs/sam3d/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 167, in run
    cmd = self.call_command('install_lib', warn_dir=0)
  File "/home/makogan/anaconda3/envs/sam3d/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 153, in call_command
    self.run_command(cmdname)
  File "/home/makogan/anaconda3/envs/sam3d/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/home/makogan/anaconda3/envs/sam3d/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 989, in run_command
    super().run_command(command)
  File "/home/makogan/anaconda3/envs/sam3d/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/home/makogan/anaconda3/envs/sam3d/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/install_lib.py", line 11, in run
    self.build()
  File "/home/makogan/anaconda3/envs/sam3d/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/install_lib.py", line 111, in build
    self.run_command('build_ext')
  File "/home/makogan/anaconda3/envs/sam3d/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/home/makogan/anaconda3/envs/sam3d/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 989, in run_command
    super().run_command(command)
  File "/home/makogan/anaconda3/envs/sam3d/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/home/makogan/anaconda3/envs/sam3d/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 88, in run
    _build_ext.run(self)
  File "/home/makogan/anaconda3/envs/sam3d/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 345, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "/home/makogan/anaconda3/envs/sam3d/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 871, in build_extensions
    build_ext.build_extensions(self)
  File "/home/makogan/anaconda3/envs/sam3d/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 467, in build_extensions
    self._build_extensions_serial()
  File "/home/makogan/anaconda3/envs/sam3d/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 493, in _build_extensions_serial
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "/home/makogan/anaconda3/envs/sam3d/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 249, in build_extension
    _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
  File "/home/makogan/anaconda3/envs/sam3d/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 548, in build_extension
    objects = self.compiler.compile(
  File "/home/makogan/anaconda3/envs/sam3d/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 675, in unix_wrap_ninja_compile
    cuda_post_cflags = unix_cuda_flags(cuda_post_cflags)
  File "/home/makogan/anaconda3/envs/sam3d/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 574, in unix_cuda_flags
    cflags + _get_cuda_arch_flags(cflags))
  File "/home/makogan/anaconda3/envs/sam3d/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/cpp_extension.py", line 1976, in _get_cuda_arch_flags
    arch_list[-1] += '+PTX'
IndexError: list index out of range

I have tried reinstalling cuda and rebooting my computer both without success, what can I try?

https://github.com/IDEA-Research/GroundingDINO/issues/127

Solution link from what @talonmies posted: https://github.com/IDEA-Research/GroundingDINO/issues/127#issuecomment-1571718150

For posterity, that link was the first hit when searching for “ UserWarning: There are no g++ version bounds defined for CUDA version 11.8”
